# Ansible - Group Variables with Dynamic Inventory

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

Im attempting to start using ansible, and my current project is deploying a Graylog cluster.  I operate in AWS and would need to handle dynamic inventory.  I think I am missing the link betweek my playbooks and the dynamic instances getting the variables defined in the group variables.

Here is my directory structure. https://pastebin.com/cuNH4bzX

Here is my tag_Application_graylog file https://pastebin.com/Vw0cbnZq

When I am in the play directory, I am able to connect to instances using that tag.

```
ubuntu@ip-10-128-0-86:~/deployments/plays$ ansible -m ping tag_Application_graylog
ec2_justin_graylog01_dev | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false, 
    "failed": false, 
    "ping": "pong"
}
ec2_justin_graylog02_dev | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false, 
    "failed": false, 
    "ping": "pong"
}
```

When i attempt to run the play, I get the following error.

```
TASK [elastic.elasticsearch : os-specific vars] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/ubuntu/deployments/roles/elastic.elasticsearch/tasks/main.yml:2
ok: [ec2_justin_graylog01_dev] => {"ansible_facts": {"default_file": "/etc/default/elasticsearch", "es_home": "/usr/share/elasticsearch", "java": "{% if es_java is defined %}{{es_java}}{% else %}openjdk-8-jre-headless{% endif %}"}, "ansible_included_var_files": ["/home/ubuntu/deployments/roles/elastic.elasticsearch/vars/Debian.yml"], "changed": false, "failed": false}
ok: [ec2_justin_graylog02_dev] => {"ansible_facts": {"default_file": "/etc/default/elasticsearch", "es_home": "/usr/share/elasticsearch", "java": "{% if es_java is defined %}{{es_java}}{% else %}openjdk-8-jre-headless{% endif %}"}, "ansible_included_var_files": ["/home/ubuntu/deployments/roles/elastic.elasticsearch/vars/Debian.yml"], "changed": false, "failed": false}

TASK [elastic.elasticsearch : fail] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/ubuntu/deployments/roles/elastic.elasticsearch/tasks/elasticsearch-parameters.yml:3
fatal: [ec2_justin_graylog01_dev]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "es_instance_name must be specified and cannot be blank"}
fatal: [ec2_justin_graylog02_dev]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "es_instance_name must be specified and cannot be blank"}
    to retry, use: --limit @/home/ubuntu/deployments/plays/graylog.retry

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ec2_justin_graylog01_dev   : ok=6    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1   
ec2_justin_graylog02_dev   : ok=6    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

since 'es_instance_name' is defined in my group vars, I am lead to believe they are not being read in.

The command I am using to run the playbook, from within the plays folder.

```
ansible-playbook -vv graylog.yml
```

Full output of the command. https://pastebin.com/NxNFVbBG

Contents of graylog.yml https://pastebin.com/Liq8qCDi

Any help would be great.

Comment: What command are you using to run the playbook?

Comment: I have added the command, and the non debug output to the post.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you also post the contents of `graylog.yml`?

Comment: I added it to the end of the post.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue.

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/16878

Basically, group_vars needs to be an adjacent folder to the play.  So I either needded to move my play's up a level, or bring the group var folders down a level.

Based on the posted best practices, I moved my plays up a level.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_best_practices.html#content-organization